# How do parse this string in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing, text, split

I have a block of text I need to parse (saved in a variable) but I'm unsure how to go about it. This block of text, saved in a variable we can call `$block` for simplicity's sake, includes all the whitespace shown below.

I would like the result to be an iterable list, the first value being `Health_AEPOEP_Membership_Summary - Dev` and the second one being `Health_AEPOEP_YoY_Comparison_Summary - Dev`. Assume this list of workbooks can be longer (up to 50) or shorter (minimum 1 workbook), and all workbooks are formatted similarly (in terms of `name_with_underscores - Dev`. I'd try the `$block.split(" ")` method, but this method gives many spaces which may be hard to enumerate and account for.

```
                    Workbooks : Health_AEPOEP_Membership_Summary - Dev [Project: Health - Dev]
                                Health_AEPOEP_YoY_Comparison_Summary - Dev [Project: Health - Dev]
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You will learn everything you need when you watch this video: [Sophisticated Techniques of Plain Text Parsing](https://youtu.be/_cQFm5GlgxY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a multi-line regex pattern and try to extract the names, but it might be easier to reason about if you just breaking it into simple(r) steps:

```
$string = @'

                    Workbooks : Health_AEPOEP_Membership_Summary - Dev [Project: Health - Dev]
                                Health_AEPOEP_YoY_Comparison_Summary - Dev [Project: Health - Dev]



'@

# Split into one string per line
$strings = $string -split '\r?\n'

# Remove leading whitespace
$strings = $strings -replace '^\s*' 

# Remove `Workbooks : ` prefix (strings that don't match will be left untouched)
$strings = $strings -replace '^Workbooks :\s*' 

# Remove `[Project $NAME]` suffix
$strings = $strings -replace '\s*\[Project: [^\]]+\]'

# Get rid of empty lines
$strings = $strings |Where-Object Length
```

`$strings` now contains the two project names

Comment: And I've heard SO should not be a free code writing service. ;-)

Comment: when i run this, the `[Project...]` text remains. Why is that?

Comment: @AmeeraKhan There was a typo in the regex pattern (I forgot to escape the `[`), I've updated it now

Answer (score 1):

If the text is in a file it would make this a little easier, and I would recommend this approach

```
switch -Regex -file ($file){
    '(\w+_.+- Dev)' {$matches.1}
}
```

**Regex details**

`()` - capture group

`\w+` - match one or more letter characters

`_` - match literal underscore

`.+` - match one or more of any character

`- Dev` - literal match of dash space Dev

If it's already in a variable, it would depend if it's a string array or a single string. Assuming it's a single string, I'd recommend this approach

```
$regex = [regex]'(\w+_.+)(?=(\s\[.+))'

$regex.Matches($block).value

Health_AEPOEP_Membership_Summary - Dev
Health_AEPOEP_YoY_Comparison_Summary - Dev
```

**Regex details**

Same as above but added the following

`(?=)`     - Look ahead

`\s\[.+` - match a space, a left square bracket, one or more characters

Simply add a variable assignment `$strings =` before either of these to capture the output. Either would work on one or 500 workbooks.

Comment: Hmm... when I run the second option, it seems like the `[Project...]` portion remains. When I run the first suggestion, only the ] character is removed, not everything else within brackets. Why would that be? EDIT: the first solution works when I add a space after the `- Dev` in the regex expression.